# Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3) (2,2)

Tags: python

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import math as m 
a=np.array([[1,6,2],[4,5,0],[3,7,8]])

b=np.array([[4,1],[2,5]])
print(a*a*b,'\n')
```

Error:

```
Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3) (2,2)
```

How can I solve this problem, plus I'm new in python.

Any suggestion.

Comment: you can't multiple a 3x3 matrix with a 2x2 matrix. If the second one was 1x3, 3x1, or scalar you can define multiplication (broadcasting), but not if the dimensions don't match.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can sadly not be solved, as mathematically you can not multiply a 2x2 matrix and a 3x3 matrix together.